# Detecting client disconnects within gevent

Tags: python, exception, gevent, disconnect

How should I detect if a client has disconnected from my gevent webserver if I use a queue to generate response data? Right now I keep getting the `Broken pipe` error, but I don't quite understand where I should catch this exception (the traceback only includes gevent's own `pywsgi.py` and `socket.py` files and none of my code). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do that if you're returning a queue from your WSGI app (If I understood correctly what you're doing).

If you can structure your application in a different way and use WSGI's write() then you can catch socket exceptions like this:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    write = start_response('200 OK', [])
    try:
       write("response")
    except socket.error, ex:
       print ex
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Now I use a queue for transmitting data between the greenlets (messages are produced elsewhere) and send data using wsgi write().